# Error 91 - object variable or with block variable not set

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, office-automation

I'm trying to run a macro within Excel to open a specified Word doc, find a table via its bookmark name and then add a few rows to it.

It sometimes works and sometimes comes up with error 91 on the bookmarks part of the code, but I'm not sure what is causing this.

```
Dim wordApp As Word.Application
Dim fileName As String
Dim wordTable As Word.Table
Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
Dim numRows
Dim numCols
Dim excelTable As ListObject

fileName = "C:\Users\Smith\Documents\example.docx"
Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wordApp.Visible = True
Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(fileName)

'This is where the error comes:
Set wordTable = wordDoc.Bookmarks("tableA").Range.Tables(1)

wordTable.Borders.Enable = True

For i = 1 To numCols
    wordTable.Rows.Add
    Next
```

Edit: If I have a word document open (blank or a different one), the code runs fine. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

The following line of code contains multiple property and method calls:

```
Set wordTable = wordDoc.Bookmarks("tableA").Range.Tables(1)
```

So, I'd suggest breaking the chain of property calls by declaring each of them on separate lines. So, you will be able to find what property or method is causing the issue.

Also I'd suggest checking whether such bookmark exists in the document by using the following code:

```
If wordDoc.Bookmarks.Exists("temp") = True Then 
  ' your code here
End If
```

Comment: I just added that If statement to display a message box if it exists. With no word documents opened, the first time it said it exists. I then closed it without saving and tried again a few moments later. This time, it errors out on the If statement with error 91.

Comment: the code seems to work if I already have a blank or different word document open. But, if there's no word application/document open at all, it runs into the error 91.